# Bottom Navigation not working but working for another activity

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

I'm using 3 bottom navigation actives for my 3 different accounts but for some reason only one is working. It is the exact same auto-generated code but I've changed the variables etc. The shelter account works fine but for the other accounts they show the start fragment but won't switch between the others when the bottom navigation is clicked. After looking over this a lot I am unsure what is wrong and was hoping if anyone would know? If not I will try find another way of doing this. Thank you!

This is the restaurant account that isn't working.
Class:

```
public class RestaurantActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_restaurant);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.restaurant_home, R.id.restaurant_account, R.id.restaurant_settings)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.restaurant_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    }
}
```

Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/general_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/restaurant_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/restaurant_navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Navigation layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/restaurant_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/restaurant_home"
        android:name="com.example.feedthehomeless.RestaurantUI.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/restaurant_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/restaurant_account"
        android:name="com.example.feedthehomeless.RestaurantUI.account.AccountFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/restaurant_account" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/restaurant_settings"
        android:name="com.example.feedthehomeless.RestaurantUI.settings.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_notifications"
        tools:layout="@layout/restaurant_settings" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: Hi. Are you using the same layout for all activities?

Comment: No separate layouts for the different activities

Comment: Be sure that you Navigation View id is different for every activity.

Comment: Thanks changed the navigation layout ids but still didn't work